# Flutter crashes on startup: Didn't find class .MainActivity on path DexPathList

Tags: java, android, flutter, gradle

I'm using Flutter with the MultiDex builder enabled for Android and encountered a pretty tricky issue. My app was running without any exceptions but when the `video_player` package was added it just crashed on startup:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.rsg.anygoal, PID: 5883
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.rsg.anygoal/com.rsg.anygoal.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.rsg.anygoal.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.rsg.anygoal-tCKWlQXJD-iwdHtVRl0qqA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.rsg.anygoal-tCKWlQXJD-iwdHtVRl0qqA==/lib/x86, /data/app/com.rsg.anygoal-tCKWlQXJD-iwdHtVRl0qqA==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.rsg.anygoal.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.rsg.anygoal-tCKWlQXJD-iwdHtVRl0qqA==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.rsg.anygoal-tCKWlQXJD-iwdHtVRl0qqA==/lib/x86, /data/app/com.rsg.anygoal-tCKWlQXJD-iwdHtVRl0qqA==/base.apk!/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:125)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1174)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2669)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Later while investigating the issue I tried to disable MultiDex and that seemingly fixed it, but then adding additional flutter package broke the app again, so I decided it's not strictly caused by multiDex and re-enabled it.

Another fix attempt I found in forums was to rename `".MainActivity"` to the exact class path `"com.*...*.MainActivity"` but that did not help either.

Hopefully someone will suggest a possible fix to this! Leaving a few more logs and code snippets I collected during my investigation, which may include clues helpful to you.

***Full Android logcat logs: https://pastebin.com/vPs614jj***

***Flutter pubspec (name and description intentionally omitted):***

```yaml
version: 1.0.6+16
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  intl: ^0.15.8
  firebase_core: ^0.4.3+1
  firebase_admob: ^0.9.0+10
  firebase_analytics: ^5.0.9
  firebase_auth: ^0.15.3
  firebase_crashlytics: ^0.1.2+4
  firebase_performance: ^0.3.1+5
  firebase_remote_config: ^0.3.0+1
  firebase_messaging: ^6.0.9
  firebase_dynamic_links: ^0.5.0+9
  cloud_firestore: ^0.13.0+1
  cloud_functions: ^0.4.1+6
  google_sign_in: ^4.1.1
  provider: ^4.0.1
  data_connection_checker: ^0.3.4
  shared_preferences: ^0.5.6
  flutter_markdown: ^0.3.2
  url_launcher: ^5.4.1
  barcode_scan: ^1.0.0
  qr_flutter: ^3.2.0
  share: ^0.6.3+5
  video_player: ^0.10.11+2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:
  fonts:
    - family: Raleway
      fonts:
        - asset: fonts/Raleway-Regular.ttf
  uses-material-design: true
```

***Android Manifest:***

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="$APP_DOMAIN">
    <application android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication" android:label="$APP_NAME" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <meta-data android:name="io.flutter.app.android.SplashScreenUntilFirstFrame" android:value="true" />
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID" android:value="$APP_ADS_ID"/>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
            android:resource="@drawable/notification_icon" />
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
</manifest>
```

***MainActivity.java:***

```java
import android.os.Bundle;
import io.flutter.app.FlutterActivity;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;

public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this);
  }
}
```

***Flutter doctor output (XCode shouldn't matter):***

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.17.5, on Mac OS X 10.15.4 19E287, locale en-BG)
 
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
[!] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    ✗ Xcode installation is incomplete; a full installation is necessary for iOS development.
      Download at: https://developer.apple.com/xcode/download/
      Or install Xcode via the App Store.
      Once installed, run:
        sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
        sudo xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.46.1)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)
```

Comment: Did you found any solution? I face this problem too..  @Radi Cho

Comment: @fajarainul Check out my comment on GitHub with possible workaround: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/60831#issuecomment-654070155

Comment: your solution is not working for me. Do you have any other solution?

Comment: My project use firebase cloud messaging https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging/versions/5.1.8 (I use v.5.1.8 and cant update for several reasons) and want to handle background messages. When I add Application.java to AndroidManifest.xml an error occurred. This is the log 

Didn't find class "id.kasku.kasku_mobile_flutter.Application" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/id.kasku.kasku_mobile_flutter-2/base.apk"].

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My findings suggest this is not an issue with Flutter itself, but occurs after particular Flutter package installations.
After upgrading Gradle and the AndroidX libraries, the crash disappeared and then re-appeared after another Flutter package addition. Then I cleaned *(`build->clean` in the IDE)* the android project again and it was fixed once again. So it may be due to some Gradle confusions in my environment and probably it just doesn't compile some classes the right way from time to time.

Comment: This is wrong. It's not a problem with Flutter. It happened to me after I changed the package name using the change_app_package_name from pub.dev. Apparently It did not change the package name in all places. It did not change the MainActivity.kt and project.pbxproj files. I did a search and replace and this fixed the problem.

Comment: Clean the project then rebuild it, works for me fine

Answer (score 59):

I had similar error, after a "package name" change.
My solution was:
Update package name also in MainActivity.kt.

In short, all package names should be fixed accordingly.

after that, it is fixed.

Comment: This worked for me. I did a search and replaced and replaced all the old package names with the new one. I had used the change_app_package_name library from pub.dev - but it did not change the MainActivity.kt and project.pbxproj files. The search replace fixed this.

Comment: this is the correct answer, best regards bro

Comment: I actually needed to add a new package with the correct name, move the updated .kt file into it, then delete the old. Thanks for this answer @ehcp.

Comment: This is the right answer.

Answer (score 12):

**Solution:**
Its simple solution is to go to MainActivity.kt and match the Package-name with AndroidManifest.xml.

Answer (score 6):

The simplest way to solve this if using Android Studio/Flutter is to:

1:Stop the app,then Open MainActivity.kt:

```
path : "**android/src/main/kotlin/MainActivity.kt**"
```

If your package name in MainActivity does not match your app,update it in your MainActivity.kt.
[image: Android Studio]

2:Then go to ***Edit>Find > Replace in Files*** and replace the previous package name with the new one across the entire app and all files.Restart Android Studio before proceeding to the next step.(Invalidate Caches and Restart)

3:After the restart...Open app/src/build.gradle and enable multidex:

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.your.apppackage"
    minSdkVersion 28
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
    versionName flutterVersionName
    multiDexEnabled true //add multidex enabled
}
```

...and dont forget to add the multidex dependency in the same gradle file:

```
**dependencies {**
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1' // add it as a dependency here
}
```

and finally invalidate caches and restart.
(**`File>Invalidate Caches/Restart`**).

Comment: Could you add some explanation for what multiDex does?

Comment: Hi LabGecko ,Thats a good question.
I found an excellent walkthrough of multidex for you here: 
   https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/multidex-in-android/

Answer (score 4):

This happened to me when I [partially] renamed the package name (app ID) from com.example.myappone to com.myapp.one. I thought it'd be sufficient to change just the values in `android/app/src/mainAndroidManifest.xml` and `ios/Runner.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj`.

Turns out the actual package names also need to be changed so that the source files are located by the compiler

Answer (score 4):

This is not a beautiful solution but it works.
For some reason the dex files doesn't have a MainActivity compiled

So we added to the manifest the `FlutterActivity` directly and that fixed the problem to us

```
<application
        android:label="morari"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name="io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity"
            ...>
            ...
 </application>
```

Dex files:

[image]

Comment: Works perfectly

Answer (score 3):

In my case, this happened when I accidentally commented out (removed) the line:

```
package com.mypackagename
```

from "MainActivity.kt" file while I was editing it! Simply adding it back solved the problem.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I changed the package name of my Flutter project from the default and did not update the package name on the MainActivity.kt file.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Possible Reason: Tags not placed properly in Manifest file is one of this error's causes .

**Solution**: Ensure all the tags are properly placed in /src/main's  AndroidManifest.xml file .

Answer (score 1):

New solution in 2023, Go to `AndroidManifest.xml` change

```
<application
   android:name="com.steam.mobile.Application"
```

to

```
<application
   android:name="${applicationName}"
```

Comment: I had that set in my AndroidManifest.xml, but still got this error. If the package name is set in MainActivity.kt it must match whatever is being used in Flutter, like in @RileyManda's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69883259/2748201

Answer (score 0):

I don't know but for some reason my MainActivity.java was missing so i created one and woola the app is working.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, it was because of the package name, so I just renamed the package name and it worked for me

```
Go to build.gradle in the app module and rename applicationId "com.company.name"

Go to Manifest.xml in app/src/main and rename package="com.company.name" and android:label="App Name"

Go to Manifest.xml in app/src/debug and rename package="com.company.name"

Go to Manifest.xml in app/src/profile and rename package="com.company.name"

Go to app/src/main/kotlin/com/something/something/MainActivity.kt and rename package="com.company.name"


Go to app/src/main/kotlin/ and rename each directory so that the structure looks like app/src/main/kotlin/com/company/name/

Go to pubspec.yaml in your project and change name: something to name: name, example :- if package name is com.abc.xyz the name: xyz

Go to each dart file in lib folder and rename the imports to the modified name.
```

so, in short, it's just that your app has a **different package name in one of the above dir**, so make sure your **package name is the same everywhere**.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I used the `APG Upgrade assistant` of Android Studio and also checked that the package definition should be moved from Manifest to `build.gradle`.

After the bundle identifier was not there in `AndroidManifest` any more this error was thrown.