# FATAL EXCEPTION: main, having an error while starting app / Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am having some error while starting my android app down below. I think it has to do with AndroidManifest.xml Thank you for help in advance!

**Debug console output:**

```
√ Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
E/AndroidRuntime(12850): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(12850): Process: com.example.finalproject, PID: 12850
E/AndroidRuntime(12850): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.finalproject-TKk2pSYMBdlivmhMJqry9A==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.finalproject-TKk2pSYMBdlivmhMJqry9A==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.example.finalproject-TKk2pSYMBdlivmhMJqry9A==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/product/lib64]]
E/AndroidRuntime(12850):    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:1230)
E/AndroidRuntime(12850):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6575)
E/AndroidRuntime(12850):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:227)
E/AndroidRuntime(12850):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1890)
E/AndroidRuntime(12850):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
E/AndroidRuntime(12850):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
E/AndroidRuntime(12850):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7590)
E/AndroidRuntime(12850):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

Didn't find class "io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.finalproject-TKk2pSYMBdlivmhMJqry9A==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.finalproject-TKk2pSYMBdlivmhMJqry9A==/lib/arm64, /data/app/com.example.finalproject-TKk2pSYMBdlivmhMJqry9A==/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /system/product/lib64]]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter crashes on startup: Didn't find class .MainActivity on path DexPathList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62728362/flutter-crashes-on-startup-didnt-find-class-mainactivity-on-path-dexpathlist)

Comment: @nuts i have a quick question, so i have to update flutter package right? I had plenty of issues with newest version flutter as my code previously working alright and then after update there was alot of errors due code changes

Comment: Finally i needed to clean it worked out with 'flutter clean'

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an issue in the references that the Flutter project uses. You can run either `flutter clean` or `flutter pub cache repair` to help rebuild the references used in the project, then run `flutter pub get` to download the configured plugins.